# Why does Git say my master branch is "already up to date" even though it is not?

Tags: git, github, merge

### Basic Problem

I just deleted ALL the code from a file in my project and committed the change to my local git (on purpose). I did

```
git pull upstream master
```

to fetch and merge from upstream (so in theory that deleted code should be back).

Git tells me everything is up to date.

Everything is definitely NOT up to date -- all that deleted code is still deleted.

#### Other Relevant Info

I only have one branch called "master".

I recently set up "master" to track upstream like so:

> Branch master set up to track remote branch master from upstream.

The command `git branch -vv` yields:

```
* master 7cfcb29 [upstream/master: ahead 9] deletion test
```

Why why why is this happening?  I'm on the verge of just e-mailing my project manager any changes I make to our code.

### Update

I thought it was obvious, but anyways this is my goal:

**Get the most recent of the code on my system.**

Excuse my anger here, but why does such a simple task as that have to be so hard?

Comment: It is obvious that if you delete your source then try pulling with a straightforward "pull" that git will not override your local changes (in this case your deletions) without ensuring you really want to override your local changes. The first answer seems to explain exactly how you can go about it.

Answer (score 262, accepted):

I think your basic issue here is that you're misinterpreting and/or misunderstanding what git does and why it does it.

When you clone some other repository, git makes a copy of whatever is "over there".  It also takes "their" branch labels, such as `master`, and makes a copy of that label whose "full name" in *your* git tree is (normally) `remotes/origin/master` (but in your case, `remotes/upstream/master`).  Most of the time you get to omit the `remotes/` part too, so you can refer to that original copy as `upstream/master`.

If you now make and commit some change(s) to some file(s), you're the only one with those changes.  Meanwhile other people may use the original repository (from which you made your clone) to make other clones and change those clones.  They are the only ones with their changes, of course.  Eventually though, someone may have changes they send back to the original owner (via "push" or patches or whatever).

The `git pull` command is mostly just shorthand for `git fetch` followed by `git merge`.  This is important because it means you need to understand what those two operations actually do.

The `git fetch` command says to go back to wherever you cloned from (or have otherwise set up as a place to fetch from) and find "new stuff someone else added or changed or removed".  Those changes are copied over and applied *to your copy of what you got from them earlier*.  They are *not* applied to your own work, only to theirs.

The `git merge` command is more complicated and is where you are going awry.  What it does, oversimplified a bit, is compare "what you changed in your copy" to "changes you fetched from someone-else and thus got added to your-copy-of-the-someone-else's-work".  If your changes and their changes don't seem to conflict, the `merge` operation mushes them together and gives you a "merge commit" that ties your development and their development together (though there is a very common "easy" case in which you have no changes and you get a "fast forward").

The situation you're encountering now is one in which you have made changes and committed them—nine times, in fact, hence the "ahead 9"—and they have made *no* changes.  So, `fetch` dutifully fetches nothing, and then `merge` takes their lack-of-changes and also does nothing.

What you want is to look at, or maybe even "reset" to, "their" version of the code.

If you merely want to look at it, you can simply check out that version:

```
git checkout upstream/master
```

That tells git that you want to move the current directory to the branch whose full name is actually `remotes/upstream/master`.  You'll see their code as of the last time you ran `git fetch` and got their latest code.

If you want to *abandon* all your own changes, what you need to do is change git's idea of which revision your label, `master`, should name.  Currently it names your most recent commit.  If you get back onto that branch:

```
git checkout master
```

then the `git reset` command will allow you to "move the label", as it were.  The only remaining problem (assuming you're really ready to abandon everything you've don) is finding where the label should point.

`git log` will let you find the numeric names—those things like `7cfcb29`—which are permanent (never changing) names, and there are a ridiculous number of other ways to name them, but in this case you just want the name `upstream/master`.

To move the label, wiping out your own changes (any that you have committed are actually recoverable for quite a while but it's a lot harder after this so be *very* sure):

```
git reset --hard upstream/master
```

The `--hard` tells git to wipe out what you have been doing, move the current branch label, and then check out the given commit.

It's not super-common to *really* want to `git reset --hard` and wipe out a bunch of work.  A safer method (making it a lot easier to recover that work if you decide some of it was worthwhile after all) is to rename your existing branch:

```
git branch -m master bunchofhacks
```

and then make a new local branch named `master` that "tracks" (I don't really like this term as I think it confuses people but that's the git term :-) ) the origin (or upstream) master:

```
git branch -t master upstream/master
```

which you can then get yourself on with:

```
git checkout master
```

What the last three commands do (there's shortcuts to make it just two commands) is to change the name pasted on the existing label, then make a new label, then switch to it:

before doing anything:

```
C0 -    "remotes/upstream/master"
    \
     \- C1 --- C2 --- C3 --- C4 --- C5 --- C6 --- C7 --- C8 --- C9    "master"
```

after `git branch -m`:

```
C0 -    "remotes/upstream/master"
    \
     \- C1 --- C2 --- C3 --- C4 --- C5 --- C6 --- C7 --- C8 --- C9    "bunchofhacks"
```

after `git branch -t master upstream/master`:

```
C0 -    "remotes/upstream/master", "master"
    \
     \- C1 --- C2 --- C3 --- C4 --- C5 --- C6 --- C7 --- C8 --- C9    "bunchofhacks"
```

Here `C0` is the latest commit (a complete source tree) that you got when you first did your `git clone`.  C1 through C9 are your commits.

Note that if you were to `git checkout bunchofhacks` and then `git reset --hard HEAD^^`, this would change the last picture to:

```
C0 -    "remotes/upstream/master", "master"
    \
     \- C1 --- C2 --- C3 --- C4 --- C5 --- C6 --- C7 -    "bunchofhacks"
                                                      \
                                                       \- C8 --- C9
```

The reason is that `HEAD^^` names the revision two up from the head of the current branch (which just before the reset would be `bunchofhacks`), and `reset --hard` then moves the label.  Commits C8 and C9 are now mostly invisible (you can use things like the reflog and `git fsck` to find them but it's no longer trivial).  Your labels are yours to move however you like.  The `fetch` command takes care of the ones that start with `remotes/`.  It's conventional to match "yours" with "theirs" (so if they have a `remotes/origin/mauve` you'd name yours `mauve` too), but you can type in "theirs" whenever you want to name/see commits you got "from them".  (Remember that "one commit" is an entire source tree.  You can pick out one specific file from one commit, with `git show` for instance, if and when you want that.)

Comment: I learned a lot from your excellent answer. But I'm still confused as to why I get the git status message: "Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'" when the upstream repo is several commits ahead of my current repo. I can get up-to-date with git pull, but how do I know that I need to pull if the message says I'm up-to-date?

Comment: @ChristopherWerby: it sounds like you're running `git merge` as a command-line command (which is something I do myself, it's a reasonable method).  Note, though, that `git pull` starts by first running `git fetch`, *then* running `git merge` (or `git rebase` if you tell it to do that instead).  It's the *fetch* step that actually brings over the new commits to be merged (or rebased-only).

Comment: @torek Is there some command, other than `git status`, that I can use to see if the upstream repo is ahead of my current repo?  The message that I get with `git status` that says "Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'" confuses me into thinking I've got the latest changes, when I don't.  Sometimes, I do get a message which says something like "origin/master is 5 commits ahead of your branch" (paraphrasing).  But it's not consistent.

Comment: @ChristopherWerby: It's a pair of commands, `git fetch` first, then `git status`.  You can make an alias that does both, if you want.  There's also `git ls-remote`, which will get the SHA-1s from the remote (this is the first step of a real `git fetch`), but those are pretty much useless to humans, and if your network is fast, doing a full `git fetch` is not much slower (and is useful), so generally you probably should just `git fetch`.

Comment: @torek Oh!  Now I understand your first answer to me.  I've never used `git fetch` as a standalone command.  Now I get it!  Thanks!

Comment: BTW that comment with "(or rebased-only)" has a brain-o (fancier version of typo), it should say "(or rebased-onto)".

Comment: Can I just delete a banchofhacks after all above steps with git branch -d banchofhacks?

Comment: @JanatbekSharsheyev: yes, provided you have first checked out some other branch name (Git won't let you delete the *current* branch). Note that deleting the *name* may make the commits themselves "unreachable", in Git's terminology. If so, those commits become eligible for what Git calls *garbage collection*. If you don't want or need them any more, this is probably what you want anyway.

Comment: I just created angular components to test an application, but to delete a component that was generated automatically by CLI I had to go through all files where angular made changes. so I thought to just remove that branch completely, Thank you for quick interaction.

Comment: This still doesn't actually answer why `git status` says "Your branch is up to date" when an immediate `git fetch` then pulls down over a hundred objects and resolves almost a hundred deltas, mentions several new branches and a couple of new tags and changes the main (remote tracking) branch head commit - and then another git status cheerily, and disingenuously, still says "Your branch is up to date". Clearly a lot came down from origin but the branch was "up to date with origin" both before and after?

Comment: @NeilG: there are a lot of ways to think about it, but perhaps the most important is this: *your* branch `master` is not the same as *their* branch `master`. In this case there are two of "them"—`origin` and `upstream`—so there are three `master`s; and your master isn't even associated with one of these three `master`s. It *is* one of the three, and is associated with another, but not with the third. Not all cases fall into this particular trap, but if you have both `origin` and `upstream`, some do.

Comment: Thanks @torek, I've found some clarity here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37694515/git-status-vs-fetch-or-pull-how-to-know-what-up-to-date-means-without-chan The critical point to realise is the "remote tracking branch" is actually *local*, and *not* kept automatically up to date. So prior to the `fetch` the `git status` is just comparing to the *local* (remote) tracking branch, which is still old. `status` does not compare to the *actual* remote branch. The `fetch` brings the changes from the remote to the *local* (remote) tracking branch and then `status` can make sense.

Comment: great answer    git fetch   with    git pull    does the trick

Comment: @PhilipRego: The TL;DR is that it *is* up to date. Git is correct. The above is all about why Git is correct and how to tell Git that you want something other than what it is already doing.

Comment: Ok sorry I think my question is different. I'm wondering why git says `$ git status
On branch release/2019
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/release/2019'.`
It says it's up to date, but when I pull it still pulls things. 
`$ git pull
remote: Counting objects: 32, done.
`

Comment: `git pull` runs `git fetch` first, then `git merge` (or other second command of your choice). The `git fetch` step updates *your* Git's memory of *their* Git's status, by calling up *their* Git and getting anything new from them. Your `git status` only checks your Git's memory of their Git.

Comment: Answers like this are the pure reason why everyone has a reason to hate Git.

Answer (score 63):

I had the same problem as you.

I did `git status` `git fetch` `git pull`, but my branch was still behind to origin. I had folders and files pushed to remote and I saw the files on the web, but on my local they were missing.

Finally, these commands updated all the files and folders on my local:

```
git fetch --all
git reset --hard origin/master
```

or if you want a branch

```
git checkout your_branch_name_here
git reset --hard origin/your_branch_name_here
```

Comment: thanks! this actually worked. Keep in mind that the branch names are case sensitive!

Comment: It worked, but why does this happen?

Comment: For the people about to do git reset --hard origin/master, better to stash your local changes first as this will overwrite the changes you have in your local.

Answer (score 5):

While none of these answers worked for me, I was able to fix the issue using the following command.

`git fetch origin`

This did a trick for me.

Comment: Same! After 2 hours searching, what is the reason tho???

Comment: ```git fetch --all``` and a refresh in eclipse did the job for me!

Comment: Thanks, man. I found several answers from this site. But none of them has given a straight and working answer like you.

Answer (score 4):

Any changes you commit, like deleting all your project files, will still be in place after a pull. All a pull does is merge the latest changes from somewhere else into your own branch, and if your branch has deleted everything, then at best you'll get merge conflicts when upstream changes affect files you've deleted. So, in short, yes everything is up to date.

If you describe what outcome you'd like to have instead of "all files deleted", maybe someone can suggest an appropriate course of action.

**Update:**

> GET THE MOST RECENT OF THE CODE ON MY SYSTEM

What you don't seem to understand is that you already have the most recent code, which is yours. If what you really want is to see the most recent of *someone else's* work that's on the master branch, just do:

```
git fetch upstream
git checkout upstream/master
```

Note that this won't leave you in a position to immediately (re)start your own work. If you need to know how to undo something you've done or otherwise revert changes you or someone else have made, then please provide details. Also, consider reading up on what version control is for, since you seem to misunderstand its basic purpose.

Comment: I do in fact want the most recent version of someone else's code on my system.  However, those two commands did not do that.  All I get is "already on branch master".  The code in my files does not reflect the other person's code.

Comment: Sorry, should have been `upstream/master`. Updated my answer.

Answer (score 3):

As the other posters say, pull merges changes from upstream into your repository.  If you want to replace what is in your repository with what is in upstream, you have several options.  Off the cuff, I'd go with

```
git checkout HEAD^1  # Get off your repo's master.. doesn't matter where you go, so just go back one commit
git branch -d master  # Delete your repo's master branch
git checkout -t upstream/master  # Check out upstream's master into a local tracking branch of the same name
```

Answer (score 1):

The top answer is much better in terms of breadth and depth of information given, but it seems like if you wanted your problem fixed almost immediately, and don't mind trodding on some of the basic principles of version control, you could ...

1. Switch to master

   ```
   $ git checkout upstream master
   ```
2. Delete your unwanted branch. (Note: it must be have the -D, instead of the normal -d flag because your branch is many commits ahead of the master.)

   ```
   $ git branch -d <branch_name>
   ```
3. Create a new branch

   ```
   $ git checkout -b <new_branch_name>
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Just a friendly reminder if you have files locally that aren't in github and yet your `git status` says

> Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.
> nothing to commit, working tree clean

**It can happen if the files are in `.gitignore`**

Try running

```
cat .gitignore
```

and seeing if these files show up there. That would explain why git doesn't want to move them to the remote.

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem. Git fetch and git pull where both saying "already up to date" but I could see more pushed commits on my branch in other computers and also in the web browser (bitbucket), that were not in my code and I was unable to pull.

Nothing written here worked for me.

The only solution for me was to create a new branch (either in the web tool or in another machine), and then after checking out that new branch everything was restored.

Answer (score 0):

I just never believe it and I check out master then do a 'git pull origin master' to update my local master branch.