# Git merge branch already up to date, yet has modifications pending

Tags: git, merge

I'm new to git, and have two branches i'm trying to merge (newDevelopment and master). I messed up the file tracking somehow on my newDevelopment branch, and because so, I cannot merge the changes into master. I've tried renaming the branch and merging to no avail.

Here's what i'm looking at:

```
blabla@ip:/vol/apps/staging/current$ git diff --name-status newDevelopment..master
M       app/admin/reports.rb
M       config/resque_schedule.yml

blabla@ip:/vol/apps/staging/current$ git branch
MoreDetailsReport
* master
newDevelopment

blabla@ip:/vol/apps/staging/current$ git merge newDevelopment
Already up-to-date.
```

How do I fix this? Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps this answer can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/634546/git-merge-reports-already-up-to-date-though-there-is-a-difference?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like that you have already merged `newDevelopment` into `master`, and when you did it, you ignored some changes (reset them) and committed the merge. As a result, `master` has all revisions from `newDevelopment`, and so there's nothing more to merge into it. But the branches are different, because of the changes you ignored.

One way to fix is to make a copy of your branch for backup, then reset its history to the point before you messed things up:

```
git branch master-bak
git reset --hard SHA1
```

Find the right SHA1 using `git log`, probably it's a merge commit. After that, repeat the merge that went wrong.

Another, not so good way to fix is to get those files with the changes from the other branch:

```
git checkout newDevelopment -- app/admin/reports.rb
git checkout newDevelopment -- config/resque_schedule.yml
```

And then use `git diff --cached` to review the differences.