# Git merge not working as expected

Tags: git

I'm a total Git noob so apologies.

Ok so I have a master branch and a dev branch. I have a new feature on my dev branch that I want to merge onto my master branch. I've made all my commits and gone to do

```
git checkout master
git merge dev
```

and it says it is up to date but it's not updating my files.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Duplicate of [Git merge reports "Already up-to-date" though there is a difference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/634546/git-merge-reports-already-up-to-date-though-there-is-a-difference)

Comment: Or alternative close reason: "Lacks sufficient information to diagnose problem." `git log --oneline --graph --decorate` would give a clearer picture of what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

You should first switch to your destination branch (master) and then do the merge:

```
git checkout master
git merge dev
```

If this does not solve your problem, it probably means that either you have committed to the wrong branch, or you have already merged your work. To find out, you can use `git log --graph --all` or `gitk` to see a nice graph of your commits.

Comment: sorry, should have been clearer, that's what I've been doing