# Confusion with origin/branch and local/branch merging..?

Tags: git, github

I have a branch on GitHub (origin) called issue75.  I have a local issue75 branch that I'm trying to sync up with origin, but when I run the following...

```
git merge origin/issue75
```

I end up with a message telling me "Already up-to-date."

However, if I compare them with...

```
git diff origin/issue75
```

I do see that there are differences between the files in my local issue75 branch vs. the origin/issue75 branch.

I'm not sure how to resolve this at this point and would appreciate any assistance I can get.  Thanks!

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/634546/git-merge-reports-already-up-to-date-though-there-is-a-difference. I think the differences are only the extra on local branch.

Comment: Duplicate of [Git merge reports “Already up-to-date” though there is a difference](http://stackoverflow.com/q/634546/456814).

Comment: If you do a simple `git log --graph --oneline --decorate issue75 origin/issue75`, you'll be able to tell the relationship between your branches.