# Git: Already up to Date

Tags: git

I was unable to explain why I had this message. I had a master branch, created a new branch, made some commits and wanted to merge them back onto master, which I would have expected to cause master to fast forward. Indeed test cases confirm.

However in my search for a solution I hit this post:

[Git merge reports "Already up-to-date" though there is a difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/634546/git-merge-reports-already-up-to-date-though-there-is-a-difference/27822881#27822881)

Can anyone explain why in this example the reporter explains there would be no fast forward?

Additional information I can think of:

- I was not in a detached head mode.
- I checked back out to master to merge new branch:

  ```
   git checkout -b new-branch
   git commit -am "changes to new branch"
   git checkout master
   git merge new-branch // expect fast forward but got the already up to date msg
  ```

In a simple test case I dont get the above - so something to do with the mess of the repo, but more importantly I dont understand the rationale of the comments in the above stack overflow link - which would seem on the face of it to possibly explain something related to my scenario?

Comment: Is there a diference between the branches? Run "git diff new-branch master" to check. Have you created "new-branch" (executed "git checkout -b new-branch") with the "master" branch checkouted?

Comment: ok, ignoring what I have done - I dont get the explanation in the post I linked to - surely (answer no. 7) would do a fast forward?

Comment: If the branch you’re trying to merge is a parent of your current branch than certainly you will receive the "already up-to-date" message. On the other hand, if your current branch is a parent of the branch you're trying to merge than certainly you will receive the "fast-forward" message. Other way, you'll have a merge.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you did something like this, based on `master`:

```
$ git checkout -b newBranch
... edit some files ...
$ git commit -a
$ git merge master
Already up-to-date.
```

Now, git reports nothing to merge, because you are trying to merge changes from `master` to `newBranch`.

Try merging from `newBranch` to `master` instead, e.g.

```
$ git checkout master
$ git merge newBranch
```

Comment: sorry I did not provide enough information, see edits.