# Git merge says up to date

Tags: git, merge, git-merge

I have two Git branches for my code. `oldApp` for the old version and the new version is on the `master` branch. I made some changes in the old app code, and now I want to merge them to the new app but when I try to run `git merge` it says everything is up to date. What am I doing wrong?

More details:

I am currently on the `master` branch. This is the output of `git status`:

```
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

I am running `git merge origin/oldApp` and getting `Already up-to-date`. The `oldApp` branch was forked from the `master` branch.

gitk didn't help. When I run it in the `master` branch I can't see anything about the `oldApp` branch.

I tried pasting the output of git log --all --oneline --decorate --graph but it looks horrible here. How can I do this?

EDIT: git fetch did the trick! I was able to merge after I ran it. thanks.

Comment: Please post the exact commands used, what branch you're in etc

Comment: From your description, the relationship between those two branches is not clear. However, this is very critical to know since it actively affects the way a merge works. You need to provide more information about your situation, how those branches look like, and what you are trying to do.

Comment: gitk might help - check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/634546/git-merge-reports-already-up-to-date-though-there-is-a-difference

Comment: I am currently on the master branch: this is the output of git status:


On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
nothing to commit, working directory clean

I am running git merge origin/oldApp and getting Already up-to-date.

The oldApp branch was forked from the master branch.

Comment: gitk didn't help. When I run it in the master branch I can't see anything about the oldApp branch.

Comment: Are you sure that `oldApp` was branched off master and not the other way around? As for gitk, use `gitk --all` to see all branches.

Comment: or use gitk <branch-name> to see for a specific one

Comment: Please [edit] your post to add any additional information you have to your question. Avoid adding this in the comments, as they are harder to read and can be deleted easier. I've edited the information from your existing comments into your question.

Comment: Also, what is the output of e.g. `git log --all --oneline --decorate --graph`?

Comment: Origin/ is a local copy of the remote. Use git fetch to update this

Comment: Switch the branch to oldApp and then merge with master, make sure to pull the latest changes from master before merging.