# Can't get new files from git branch - 'Already up-to-date'

Tags: git, github

I'm new to git and am struggling with this.

I need to grab some files from a Github branch (not even sure if this is the right terminology).

I tried:

```
git pull someones-project/feature/branch-123
```

and

```
git merge someones-project/feature/branch-123
```

and got `Already up-to-date` for both.

But it's not up-to-date. I can see files on Github that are missing from my local.

Can anyone point me in the right direction here?

Comment: What does `git status` show you?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen it says ' Your branch is ahead of 'master' by 4 commits.'

Comment: Check if the files you're expecting to be updated match patterns defined in .gitignore

Comment: @Vasan thanks, I checked that - they're fine

Comment: Do you realize that you are on the `master` branch but you want to get files from the `branch-123` branch?

Comment: try taking a fresh clone. after cloning, select the desired branch from the dropdown

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen but when I do `git branch` it tells me I am in the correct one (someones-project/feature/branch-123)

Comment: Have you tried `get fetch`?

Answer (score 3):

As [mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/634575/6309):

> The message “Already up-to-date” means that all the changes from the branch you’re trying to merge have already been merged to the branch you’re currently on

So your `master` branch appears to already have the commits from `someones-project/feature/branch-123`

> `git branch` it tells me I am in the correct one (`someones-project/feature/branch-123`)

In that case, the local branch `someones-project/feature/branch-123` is already updated, and any subsequent git pull or merge will always report "already up-to-date".

As [Tim Biegeleisen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1863229/tim-biegeleisen) comments, a [`git pull`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull) should be either:

```
git pull # pulls from origin the same branch you are on
```

Or:

```
git pull origin feature/branch-123 # pull the branch from the remote 
                                   # and merges it into the current branch
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand - I can clearly see the missing files on Gtihub.com

Comment: @MeltingDog what git remote -v returns? Is it the url of the repo you are looking at?

Comment: mycompany   git@github.com:mycompany/mycompany.git (fetch)
mycompany   git@github.com:mycompany/mycompany (push)
origin  git@github.com:mycompany/mycompany.git (fetch)
origin  git@github.com:mycompany/mycompany.git (push)

Comment: @MeltingDog is `someones-project/feature/branch-123` a branch that you see in `github.com:mycompany/mycompany.git`? Is it normal that you have two remote referencing the same "`github.com:mycompany/mycompany.git`" repo?

Comment: Yes it is. Sorry, I'm not sure about your 2nd question (I'm a newb).

Comment: @MeltingDog My second question was about the output of `git remote -v`: both the remote named '`mycompany`' and the one named '`origin`' seem to reference the same url. I wanted to confirm this was the case.

Comment: @MeltingDog yet you see files missing when looking at that branch on the GitHub repo referenced by that url?

Comment: @MeltingDog If you don't have any work in progress, can you try a `git fetch` followed by a `git reset --hard origin/someones-project/feature/branch-123` and tells me if the local version of that resetted branch is now identical to the remote content you see on the remote repo?

Comment: no, I see the files I want on the GitHub repo. They're missing from my local machine. I'm trying to pull them down.

Comment: @MeltingDog OK: hence my suggestion of `fetch` + `reset --hard`.

Comment: OK I'll give that a try!

Answer (score -2):

From https://github.com/iradukundairenee/mybrand

- branch            ft-contact -> FETCH_HEAD
  Already up to date.