# pull style.css change from GitHub to online server

Tags: github, server, pull

I can not drag the style.css change from my gitrepository to that it always comes up with the message: Already up-to-date and thats wrong.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git merge reports "Already up-to-date" though there is a difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/634546/git-merge-reports-already-up-to-date-though-there-is-a-difference)

Comment: copy your css changes... clone your repo again.. paste in the changes... push them?

Comment: Why is it "wrong"?  Have you done a diff between the two files?

Answer (score 0):

Happened to me aswell , all you have to do is to manually change the css then clone the repo to you local machine apply the css changes and push it to the repo!

Comment: Thank you! but I pushed the style.css change from local to github (that was successfull) after this I tried to pull the same change on a hosted server.