# Cannot get other developer's branch on my team

Tags: git, github

I am working on the following repo with another developer.

https://github.com/practicia1234/Practicia

my branch is devSam and his branch is devSubu. Whenever he makes a new commit and pushes his code, i would like to go to his branch, pull a local version on my computer, and work on that and then push the code to my branch.

Here are the git commands i follow:

1. -git checkout devSubu
2. git pull
3. git checkout devSam
4. git merge devSubu
5. (//work on devSam)
6. git push devSam

when i am on the step "git merge devSubu" above, i get the following message and the code has not merged at all

Already up-to-date.

However, i know that my branch is not merged with devSubu and my code looks like it would on my branch, not on devSubu branch.

What am i doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

First, quick tip, you don't have to maintain a local branch devSubu, which would forces you to checkout, pull, before getting back to your own branch.

Without leaving your branch, you can at any time do:

```
git fetch
git merge origin/devSubu
```

Second, if the merge reports "Already up-to-date" ([as seen here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/634575/6309)), that means there is no new commits to merge into your branch.

Answer (score 0):

I'm try on the local, uses your steps. No problem! 
Check your steps：

1. git checkout devSubu
2. git pull
3. git checkout devSam
4. git merge devSubu
5. git push devSam